# How to find the matrix exponential in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to take the matrix exponential of a skew symmetric rotation matrix, `S`. I expect that the result is Rodrigues' rotation formula `I + sin(theta)*S + (1-cos(theta))*S*S`. However, *Mathematica* returns something that doesn't look like that formula and it's result is trying to take the square root of a negative number.

Here's my code:

```
S = { { 0, -omegaz, omegay }, {omegaz, 0, -omegax}, {-omegay, omegax, 0} };
FullSimplify[MatrixExp[S]]
```

That results in Mathematica:

[image: results]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result are the same.

In Rodrigues' rotation formula, the skew matrix is made from the unit vector, therefore you have assumption:

```
1 == omegax^2 + omegay^2 + omegaz^2
```

And you need to use:

```
MatrixExp[theta S]
```

And if you run:

```
rod = IdentityMatrix[3] + Sin[theta] S + (1 - Cos[theta]) MatrixPower[S, 2]
rod = FullSimplify[rod, Assumptions -> {omegax^2 + omegay^2 + omegaz^2 == 1}]
expS = FullSimplify[MatrixExp[theta S], Assumptions -> {omegax^2 + omegay^2 + omegaz^2 == 1}]
rod == b
(* True *)
```

Thus, the *Mathematica* calculates the rotation matrix correctly.